# What do we call a function when it's applied to a modified argument?

Tags: functions, notation

This is an embarrassingly simple question, but I realized that I haven't formalized the following idea in my mind.

Suppose we have a function $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}; x \mapsto x$. What am I to make of the notation $f(x-1)$? Is it "the same function" applied to a different argument? Is it a "different function?"

Is it a function at all? If $f(x-1)$ is the name of a function (in particular, a name for $x \mapsto f(x-1)$, where the latter $f(x-1)$ should not be confused with the former), then it ought to take an argument: $f(x-1)(y) = y-1$. It is not the same kind of creature as $f(x)$ (which is a function *application*), but is comparable to just $f$.

And yet I sometimes read things like "suppose we transform the function $f(x)$ into $f(x-1)$" in physics. It's not hard to understand what's being said, but the lack of formality in my thought is troubling me for some reason.

[image: Lenny Susskind]

Comment: You make a good point that the sentence "transform the function $f(x)$ into $f(x−1)$" somewhat lacks formality. But this has less to do with a lack of actual formalisations available and more to do with a simple abuse of notation. As Xander Henderson explains in his answer, there is a difference between defining a function and evaluating a function. In that one confusing sentence, the writer is doing both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, my question is what's the proper way to formalize it. I like your answer. We're transforming $f$ to $f \circ (x \mapsto x - 1)$.

Comment: Actually, on more thought, there's another formalization which feels more natural to me. The sentence can be interpreted as "transform the function $x \mapsto f(x)$ to $x \mapsto f(x-1)$." This way at least it's consistent.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most straightforward way to regard it is just as a function composition, which is formally defined as $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$ (taking note of well-definedness in the respective domains). So in your specific example, let $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto x - 1$, then $f(x - 1) = (f \circ g)(x)$.

And yes, to add to your additional questions, the composition of two functions is again a function, assuming the composition is well-defined. If you had a function from apples to oranges, and a function from oranges to pears, then you could have  a composition from apples to pears which is well-defined, but not a function from oranges to oranges.

Answer (score 1):

A common error committed by novice students is to confuse the *name* of a function with the *values* taken by that function.  When we write
$$ f : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto x^2, $$
then:

- $f$ is the function itself.  At a very basic level, $f$ is a set; specifically, a subset of the Cartesian product $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.  Even more specifically, in the example above, we could write
  $$ f = \{ (x,y) : y = x^2 \}. $$
- $f(x)$ is the value of the function $f$ when evaluated at the point $x$.  Stated another way, if $(x,y_x) \in f$, then $f(x) = y_x$.  In the example above, we have
  $$ f(x) = x^2, \quad
  f(-4) = 16, \quad
  f() =^2, \quad\text{and}\quad
  f(x-1) = x^2 - 2x + 1. $$

So, to clearly answer your question, $f(x-1)$ is *not* a function; $f(x-1)$ is a value in the codomain of $f$.  Specifically, it is the value obtained when $f$ is evaluated at $x-1$.  If you want to view the action $x \mapsto f(x-1)$ as a new function, you will have to introduced new notation:

- For example, define a new function
  $$ g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto f(x-1). $$
- Alternatively, in this case, it is common to think of the new function as composition with a translation.  That is, for each $a\in\mathbb{R}$, define
  $$ T_a : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto x+a. $$
  Then we have
  $$ (f\circ T_{-1})(x) = f(x-1). $$
- Another possibility is to leave a dot as placeholder for the variable.  For example, the notation $f(\cdot -1)$ indicates a function defined by the mapping $x \mapsto f(x-1)$.
- Finally, since these kind of translations show up a lot, some authors will introduce notation which specifically indicates translation.  For example, Folland (in the text *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications*) uses the notation $\tau_a$ to indicate a translation operator acting on a function.  In that text, the function $\tau_a f$ is defined by the mapping $\tau_a f(x) = f(x+a)$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response! I am familiar with most of what you wrote (though the Folland notation is new to me). As I recently commented above, I think that the easiest way for me to formalize a statement like "transform $f(x)$ into $f(x-1)$" is to take $x \mapsto f(x)$ to $x \mapsto f(x-1)$. For some strange reason whenever someone (erroneously, but commonly) talks about "the function $f(x-1)$," I mentally convert this to $x-1 \mapsto f(x-1)$ (i.e., $f$). I have to force myself to remember that the input is still just called $x$.